# Capacitor push notification error on IOS phones, full of logs on my TrackJs

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, capacitor

Im having an issue with the Push Notification plugin on IOS.
The plugins is working correctly but im getting this error log on TrackJs when my users open the app on an ios phone:

["Unhandled Promise rejection:", "event capacitorDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications not called.  Visit https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications for more information", "; Zone:", "", "; Task:", "Promise.then", "; Value:", {
"name": "Error",
"message": "event capacitorDidRegisterForRemoteNotifications not called.  Visit https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications for more information",
"stack": "R@capacitor://localhost/main.7d8a4a6c46b809b1.js:1:6947
returnResult@user-script:2:736:49
@user-script:2:718:29"
}, "R@capacitor://localhost/main.7d8a4a6c46b809b1.js:1:6947
returnResult@user-script:2:736:49
@user-script:2:718:29"]

Any ideas?

I dont know whats happening, i checked if my configuration its correctly and i saw that i have the code as the Capacitor example. Im really confused because the notifications are working fine, but my trackJs is full of this logs

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Please check if you followed all the steps from this tutorial, too. It's a little more detailed: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase

Comment: The problem was that i was doing the notification register process (add listeners, pushNotifications.register()...) on the main.ts instead of the app.component.ts